# Is direct XCMP possible ? If yes, how?

Tags: xcmp

I'm very interested to use XCMP using with the direct method, but documentation and examples are very hard to find at the current state of polkadot/substrate.

Can someone explain me how I could send direct XCMP messages using the [cumulus/relay-chain tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/connect-other-chains/local-relay/) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by direct you mean XCMP that is implemented without the full message going via the relay chain, then no that is not yet possible. It's on the roadmap after XCM v3 I believe, but the way things are coded, when this optimisation lands, it should not alter the existing APIs, it should just make XCMP message sending cheaper and more scaleable.

Comment: Ok thanks ! Cheaper XCMP could be nice !